# String trimming: Performance of while loop vs Binary Search?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, complexity-theory, trim

The standard way of trimming some characters of a string, would be to loop through each character from left to right (or right to left depending on l or r trim) and then slice it. This should have worst-case complexity O(n), if n is the length of the string, but what really matters here is how many to-be-trimmed characters I have. If I have x, it'll be O(x).

I was thinking: If I wanted to trim A TON of strings, do you think it would be possible to improve on that performance by doing a binary search? It would definitely improve worst-case runtime to O(logn), but what I'm not so sure about is whether it would improve average case runtime. How can I analyze my runtime with respect to x instead of n here?

For the implementation, I thought of simply having (For left trim):

```
leftTrim(str, start, end, i):
    if end-start == 2:
        return str[i] is trimChar ? i : -1
    if str[i] is trimChar:
        leftTrim(str, i, end, i + (end-start)/2)
    else:
        leftTrim(str, start, i, i/2)
leftTrim(str, 0, str.length, str.length/2)
```

Although it looks a little bit overcomplicated to me, it should work, right?

Comment: Binary search can only help if the characters in the string are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @OlegBarabanov No, I'm not sorting or needing to sort/search anything. I'm just going through the string by index. But instead of having to check potentially all n characters I only have to check logn+1

Comment: A binary search wouldn't parse the entire string. You're making the assumption only one place will need to be trimmed instead of several spots (e.g. "  this   has    spaces. "). A binary search would narrow down to left/right sides, but wouldn't parse the entire string.

Comment: @JosephCho But a left- or right- trim *does* only have one place at which I need to slice the string? I'm not splitting, I'm trimming after all